# Magento2.3: How to send a file to another server?

Tags: magento2.3, controllers, ftp, customer-collection

> I have a requirement that is sending the customer details like their
>   wish-list details, address, names, etc., to another server(I have all
>   the credentials for that server with me). I want to send that file via
>   admin panel so that admin can send it by one click.
>
> In order to do that, what are the things I have to do in Magento 2?
>
> Could anyone please help me with this?
>
> Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> Add button at backend customer view and create action that will
>   connect to external server.
>
> See how can one add button to customer view.
>   [How to add a button to the Customer Edit Page within the admin?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/206047/how-to-add-a-button-to-the-customer-edit-page-within-the-admin?rq=1)
>
> See how can we connect to server via code.
>   https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-connect.php
>
> If you want to do bulk operation then add new action at customer
>   listing mass action. Read here how to do that
>   https://webkul.com/blog/adding-custom-mass-action-in-admin-grid-in-magento-2/
>
> You can easily get those customers ID to your action and retrieve
>   information you want.
>
> Establish connection to database and you're good to go.
>
> Hope it will help you to get good start.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try and get back you with comments.